# Dependent dropdown using json, html and jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, json, spring-mvc

I want to fetch the state for dropdown from json and according to state the next dropdown having option of cities accordingly. How can i do it using jQuery?

Json file

```
[
    {
       "state":"Karnataka",
       "cities":["Bangalore","Vijaypura"]
    },
    {
       "state":"Bihar",
       "cities":["Patna","Gaya"]
    },
    {
       "state":"Uttar Pradesh",
       "cities":["Lucknow","Agra"]
    }
]
```

Html code

```
<div class="col-md-6">
  <label for="state">
    <spring:message code="lbl.state" text="State" /></label>
  <form:select path="state" id="state" onchange="random_function()" class="form-control" style="font-size:13px;">
    <form:option value="" label="Select State" />
    <form:option value="Karnataka" label="Karnataka" />
    <form:option value="Bihar" label="Bihar" />
    <form:option value="UttarPradesh" label="UttarPradesh" />
  </form:select>
  <div id="show_error_state" class="error"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <label for="city">
    <spring:message code="lbl.city" text="City" /></label>
  <form:select path="city" id="city" class="form-control" style="font-size:13px;">
    <form:option value="" label="Select City" />
  </form:select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse your `json` using [map](https://api.jquery.com/map/) and then append its value to your `state` dropdown and on change of `state` get value of `option` and append value of it to `city` dropdown. Working Example :

```js
//You json
var list = [{
    "state": "Karnataka",
    "cities": ["Bangalore", "Vijaypura"]
  },
  {
    "state": "Bihar",
    "cities": ["Patna", "Gaya"]
  },
  {
    "state": "Uttar Pradesh",
    "cities": ["Lucknow", "Agra"]
  }
];
//putting value in select box
options = list.map(function(val, ind) {
  //this will return values in select box
  return $("<option></option>").val(val.cities).html(val.state);
});
//appending option in select box
$('#state').append(options);

//on change of state dropdown
$("#state").on("change", function() {
  //getting selected value
  var name = $(this).val();
  console.log(name);
  //getting city value 
  var fields = name.split(',');
  var options="";
  
  //putting values inside option and append value 
  for(var i=0;i<fields.length;i++)  {
  options += '<option value="'+ fields[i]+'">'+fields[i]+'</option>';
    }
  $('#city').html(options);


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <label for="state">
    <spring:message code="lbl.state" text="State" /></label>

  <select path="state" id="state" class="form-control" style="font-size:13px;">

  </select>
  <div id="show_error_state" class="error"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <label for="city">
    <spring:message code="lbl.city" text="City" /></label>
  <select path="city" id="city" class="form-control" style="font-size:13px;">
    <option value="" label="Select City" />
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: I want cities are come after one another not seperated by comma. How to do this?